# Amazon ECS Fargate task creation through Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-deployment, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to create a ECS fargate type task on ECS through this command 
`aws ecs register-task-definition --family ${FAMILY} --cli-input-json file://${NAME}-v_${BUILD_NUMBER}.json --region ${REGION}` as mentined in docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_AWSCLI_Fargate.html#AWSCLI_register_task_definition).
Task defination file is given below

[image: task definition]
Every thing seems to work well with this command and have proper response in CLI. But when i try to do the same in Jenkins as i have to setup CI environment
it gives following error.

```
Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "cpu", must be one of: family, taskRoleArn, 
networkMode, containerDefinitions, volumes
Unknown parameter in input: "executionRoleArn", must be one of: family, 
taskRoleArn, networkMode, containerDefinitions, volumes
Unknown parameter in input: "memory", must be one of: family, taskRoleArn, 
networkMode, containerDefinitions, volumes
Unknown parameter in input: "requiresCompatibilities", must be one of: 
family, taskRoleArn, networkMode, containerDefinitions, volumes
```

If i removed those tags in task definition json file. It creates a EC2 type task which i don't need. I want to create only a fargate launch type task.
[image: Jekins commands]

Comment: I can't tell from your screenshot, what did you specify as the "launch-type" when creating your ecs service?

Comment: Launch type is fargate. Have a look on first screenshot there is a key having name "requiresCompatibilities"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I have two different aws cli's installed. And one was too old to support Fargate. I have updated cli installed on root level while jenkins user uses out of dated cli which does not support Fargate.

Answer (score 6):

From your terminal, type

`which aws`

and from Jenkins, execute the same command.

My guess is you'll find you are using two separate aws cli binaries (and one of them is too old to support Fargate.)